Why are the northern lights so much less visible to the naked eye than to smartphone cameras?
The northern lights have been visible where I live recently, but I've found them to be practically impossible to see with the naked eye.  Phone cameras, however, show them quite brilliantly.  How is this difference explained?

I think this question would be more suitable for the photography stack exchange. Anyways, did you use a specific "night mode" or did your phone say something about keeping it still while taking the photo? I suspect the photos were simply a long exposure

I haven't been able to do it personally, I've only been shown photos other people have taken.  But these were not tech-savvy people who took them, so I'm assuming they were default settings.

Appears to be a question about the physiology of the human eye. Photopic vs scotopic vision etc. The human eye is not very good at seeing colour in faint light sources.

Note that at least the iPhone cranks the color saturation way up on all the camera photos. Take a picture of a pale grey-green forest and your iphone will show it as being neon lime-green. This may be the main effect you're noticing here.

If camera didn't have right ISO, there would be nothing on the photo at all. On contrary, one can certainly view auroras well enough, if they're more intense. This q. should have gotten closed instead of becoming HNQ.

Same thing with photos of sunsets - the reds/oranges that the camera sees vs what your eye sees are two different worlds.

You have two vision systems. The daytime photopic system uses 3 types of color sensing cone receptors. This is why we see colors based on 3 primary colors. The nighttime scotopic system uses 1 type of much more sensitive rod receptor. At night, our vision is black and white. At intermediate light levels, it is possible for both systems to work.
A cell phone uses the same receptors at all light levels. Thus it can detect color at night better than we can.

Still, during a full moon night in the mountains, I could still see all the alleys around the houses and all which were fully lit, whereas my phone could only see the bright full moon. If I tried to take a photo of the alleys, the photo was entirely black.

@Clockwork - Smartphone cameras are complicated under the hood. It matters whether you have a new or old camera. This video explains a lot of how they work, starting from general camera basics. At the end, it explains night mode, which would be most relevant to you. How smartphone cameras ACTUALLY work!

@Clockwork Most cameras don't have quite the dynamic range that our eyes do. Our eyes have a fairly impressive range between the brightest and darkest that we can see. Most camera sensors will have about 1/3 or less dynamic range as our eyes. So cameras need a lot of settings and tricks to operate in all of the light conditions our eyes can see.

The cones, colour receptors, in the human eye are much less sensitive than the rods, black/white receptors so in reduced light the eye is not so good at detecting colours.  Note how things look “grey” when it is dark.
Cameras do not have this problem and to compensate for the dark conditions, a camera can just take a longer exposure and collect light for longer, building up a picture of the scene and collecting colours that the rods in the eye cannot detect.
Also, after taking a picture one can enhance it by using photo manipulation app which can change the brightness/contrast/hue/saturation/etc to enhance a display.
Here are two images illustrate the difference.

Camera

Eye
I add a comment from @JackAidley:

It's worth noting that everything taken on a phone is extensively manipulated in software before you see it. Modern phones do not simply pass on the output of the sensor.


This image has been changed by increasing the exposure using an app.

It's worth noting that everything taken on a phone is extensively manipulated in software before you see it. Modern phones do not simply pass on the output of the sensor.

@JackAidley A excellent comment which I hope is with your permission for me to incorporate in my answer.

My permission is not needed, but happily granted

@Farcher What a noble gesture!

Is "eye" just a desaturated version of "camera", or are the two separate photos taken with different settings?

Post-processing of photos is a serious problem with modern smartphone camera software, most consumers don't realise just how much of their photo is artificial. The best apps make it invisible and the worst make it gaudy, but all of them do it, and the problem only got more pervasive with the explosion of ML/DL. Relevant link from a Samsung controversy a few years ago. Yes, you're welcome to use this in the answer, I'll take any opportunity to rail against cameras that make up data instead of just capturing it.

what is meant by "exposure" in the caption for the last image: "This image has been changed by increasing the exposure using an app."? Was the sensor actually exposed for a longer time? If so that shouldn't be conflated with software manipulation imo.

@timeskull - No, I think that the exposure control on the iPhone increases the brightness of the image.  I am not aware of an exposure control, eg shutter speed, f-number, etc, on the iPhone.

@JackAidley "Modern phones do not simply pass on the output of the sensor." Probably irrelevant to the question at hand but (IMO) interestingly, neither do our eyes. There is a preprocessing into a number of 'data streams' that occurs in the eye.

@JackAidley: "Modern phones do not simply pass on the output of the sensor" - why not???  It worked just fine for film cameras and early digitals, and the electromagnetic spectrum hasn't changed since then, so why start messing with the images the camera takes?

@Vikki because people want good pictures from the tiny cameras in their phones. The physical design of phones is bad for taking good pictures, but the software gets round those limitations and lets you take much better looking pictures than you could otherwise. It also lets them remove blur from camera shake, and take far better pictures in low light and mixed light conditions, etc.

With cameras you can adjust the shutter speed which is a measure of how long the camera will gather light before it constructs the final image. More light = more visible aurora. Besides, most camera images are digitally enhanced after they are taken in order to produce a more appealing image.
You cannot do that with your eyes.
